# Center a graphviz diagram written in quarto for beamer output

Tags: quarto, beamer

I am generating diagrams using graphviz/dot inside quarto and would like them to be centered, within the column or the whole frame.

I am producing beamer pdf output (as well as docx for accessibility).

```
// | fig-width: 1.8
// | fig-align: center

graph G {
    center=true;
    node [label=""];
    
    G -- a1;
    G -- a2;
    a1 -- a11;
    a1 -- a12;
    a1 -- a13;
    a2 -- a21;
    a2 -- a22;
    a12 -- a121;
    a12 -- a122;
    a22 -- a221;
    a22 -- a222;
    a22 -- a223;
    
    G [label="G"];
}
```

I've tried looking for [centering for columns in quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/beamer.html#multiple-columns), but the align attribute there is about vertical alignment.

The center=true inside dot doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got [help from the quarto author](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/8948).  The trick seems to be to add `//| label: fig-something` and then it is written as a proper figure environment in latex.  `//| fig-align: center` then ensures I get my centering as requested.